# Get original script name included script name and possibly others

Tags: powershell

I've been testing `$MyInvocation`, `$MyCommand` and inspecting some other variables but would like a good example of how to do the following:

1. Get the name of the *current* script file
2. Get the name of the *caller* script file that included the current script file
3. Get the name of the *original* script file that ultimately resulted in #1 being executed

I have used this for *original* but maybe it will also be *caller*?

```
$myInvocation.MyCommand.Name #original
```

Even if there are more files involved, I only need the *current*, *caller* and *original*.  Consider three scripts; if you were to execute `first.ps1`:

**first.ps1**

```sh
    . "$PSScriptRoot\second.ps1"
```

**second.ps1**

```sh
    . "$PSScriptRoot\third.ps1"
    #get $Current  = second.ps1
    #get $Caller   = first.ps1 
    #get $Original = first.ps1
```

**third.ps1**

```sh
    #get $Current  = third.ps1
    #get $Caller   = second.ps1 
    #get $Original = first.ps1
```

I have worked out how to get the filename from the path etc...

**Also, why is syntax highlighting wonky on SO for PowerShell?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place the following in `second.ps1` and `third.ps1`, which utilizes the automatic `$PSCommandPath` variable and `Get-PSCallStack`:

```sh
# Get the full paths of the scripts on the call stack (the calling scripts).
$callingScripts = (Get-PSCallStack).InvocationInfo.PSCommandPath -ne $null

# For illustration, use a custom object to show the current script's 
# file name, that of the immediate caller, and that of the original caller.
[pscustomobject] @{
  Current = Split-Path -Leaf $PSCommandPath
  Caller = Split-Path -Leaf $callingScripts[0]
  Original = Split-Path -Leaf $callingScripts[-1]
}
```

Your `third.ps1` script would then output the following:

```
Current   Caller     Original
-------   ------     --------
third.ps1 second.ps1 first.ps1
```

**Explanation**:

- The [automatic `$PSCommandPath` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pscommandpath) contains the running script's own full file-system path.
- [`Get-PSCallStack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-pscallstack) outputs the call stack in the form of [`System.Management.Automation.CallStackFrame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.CallStackFrame) instances, bottom-up: that is, the instance at index `0` represents the *immediate* caller, whereas index `-1` - the *last* array element - represents the *top* of the call stack and therefore the *original* caller.
- `.InvocationInfo.PSCommandPath` is an instance of [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375), which extracts the caller script path's across all stack frames (across all array elements).

  - Non-script-*file* callers may be involved as well, notably the initial script *block* used behind the scenes to submit a command from the interactive prompt, and the `.PSCommandPath` property of such contains `$null`.
  - `-ne $null` is used to filter out these `$null` values, so that the array returned contains only the paths of script-file callers.
- [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path) `-Leaf` is used to extract just the file-name portion from the full paths.

---

> why is syntax highlighting wonky on SO for PowerShell?

Good question. It seems that some heuristic is being implied to *guess* the language, and it frequently guesses wrong; As of this writing, explicitly specifying ```` ```powershell ```` at the start of a fenced code block doesn't help, suggesting that PowerShell isn't a supported language. For now, ```` ```sh ````, even though it's the wrong language, works reasonably well in practice.

Comment: I was wondering the exact same thing about the syntax highlighting lol, someone else had to fix my own code by editing one of my answers cause I couldn't find a way to fix it myself. I guess we're to small of a community :(